# php code not running

Tags: php, android, mysql

Trying to populate a mysql database, but if i send the variables with postman or android studio i get this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>404 Not Found</body>
</html>
```

this is my php code, i leftout the db username and such for security but i assure you they are correct

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 *ordernum,pilotname,pilotcash,date,planemodel,hoobsstart,hoobsend,watchtime,hoobstime ,gas ,liter ,repairname ,repaircost ,travelexpense,othername1,othercost1
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if ( isset($_POST['pilotname']) && isset($_POST['pilotcash']) && isset($_POST['date'])  && isset($_POST['planemodel'])&& isset($_POST['hoobsstart'])&& isset($_POST['hoobsend'])&& isset($_POST['watchtime'])&& isset($_POST['hoobstime'])&& isset($_POST['gas'])&& isset($_POST['liter'])&& isset($_POST['repairname'])&& isset($_POST['repaircost'])&& isset($_POST['travelexpense'])&& isset($_POST['othername1'])&& isset($_POST['othercost1'])) {

    $pilotname = $_POST['pilotname'];
    $pilotcash = $_POST['pilotcash'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $planemodel = $_POST['planemodel'];
    $hoobsstart = $_POST['hoobsstart'];
    $hoobsend = $_POST['hoobsend'];
    $watchtime = $_POST['watchtime'];
    $hoobstime = $_POST['hoobstime'];
    $gas = $_POST['gas'];
    $liter = $_POST['liter'];
    $repairname = $_POST['repairname'];
    $repaircost = $_POST['repaircost'];
    $travelexpense = $_POST['travelexpense'];
    $othername1 = $_POST['othername1'];
    $othercost1 = $_POST['othercost1'];


     define('DB_USER', "`enter code here`"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', ""); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', ""); // db server
// array for JSON response



 $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


$sql = "INSERT INTO orden(pilotname,pilotcash,date,planemodel,hoobsstart,hoobsend,watchtime,hoobstime,gas,liter,repairname,repaircost,travelexpense,othername1,othercost1) VALUES('$pilotname','$pilotcash','$date','$planemodel','$hoobsstart','$hoobsend','$watchtime','$hoobstime','$gas','$liter','$repairname','$repaircost','$travelexpense','$othername1','$othercost1')";

    // mysql inserting a new row
   $result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error()); 

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Not running? it should be for some reason

Comment: What kind of request are you sending. Your scripts is expecting a POST method. You mention get in your question. BTW your DB is vulnerable to sql injections if your code remains like that.

Comment: it was a typo , im using postman or android studio  to send the variables it needs to run, but i get no response, i should ether get $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";or $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing"; or   $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; instead i get <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>404 Not Found</body>
</html>

Comment: how about some basic debugging like `print_r($_POST)` did you write all this code with out checking as you go?

Comment: @Dagon if i ad it anywhere i still get that result, tried it after the first if and everywhere else on the code, still no response

Comment: oh a 404, well the file is not there - um so that.

Comment: we all missed the 404 angle as its (should be) self explanatory, it doesn't matter what your code is if that is what is being returned by the server

Comment: Not much point showing us the code that does not run. **Show us the code that fails to call the right script** 404 = not found so the issue in in the calling code

Comment: Ok i debugged a bit, anything before this line $result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error());  is fine but if i try to get a result after  that with post_ r, it doesnt show

Comment: un so no 404? well im confused .. back to my paid job

Comment: Looks like you can not connect to your DB then

Comment: I have 2 tables in my db  im fine conecting to the first one that its called login with an almost identical code but for some reason it wont connect to orden wictch is the second table

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

**I bet you are not looking at your PHP Error log are you!!!**

You are not looking for a connection error after running a query you are just looking for an error

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error());
```

should be

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);
```

When using the `mysqli_` API it is a good idea Add

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

to the top of your script *While Testing only*.

This will force any `mysqli_` errors to generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

> But like I said in a comment. If your JAVA code gets a 404 error when trying to call this script, then you are not calling this script correctly. You dont show your java code so we cannot help in the debugging of that.

Comment: that did it , now it shows me what the problem was, the name of the columns in my db and here where diferent, i had a little typo, thanks a bunch, im all new to this so i didnt even know what was my real problem.